# How to list all the mount points in Azure Databricks?

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I tried with this **%fs ls dbfs:/mnt**, but i want to know do this give me all the mount point?

Answer (score 43):

I like to do the following :

```
display(dbutils.fs.mounts())
```

as it displays the databricks path and external endpoint.

[image]

I find it safer than `%sh ls /mnt/` as you can have a folder in /mnt/ that is not pointing to an external storage.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use the Databricks filesystem commands to navigate through the mount points available in your cluster.

```
%fs
mounts
```

This will give you all the mount points and also display the corresponding ADLS source file path.

Answer (score -3):

Before running this command, make sure you have created mount points earlier.

[image]

> How to list all the mount points in Azure Databricks?

Here is the list of commands to list all the mount points in Azure Databricks.

[image]

Comment: From my experience, you can have folders in dbfs:/mnt/ that are not actually mounted volumes but just simple folders.