# trouble saving Databricks dataframe into my azure storage account

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I have a databricks workspace with  json files mounted from my gen 2, I am trying to convert the json file as parquet and save in into my storage account, I created a new directory in my gen 2 where I want my parquet file to be loaded.
When I do the following code df.write.parquet("/mnt/youtubedataset/youtube/cleansed")
it doesn't seem to be saving it into my gen 2 conatiner.

what am I missing?

Comment: you haven't shown any troubleshooting steps, nor indicated whether or not there is any error.  I would suggest at the very least running `dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/youtubedataset/youtube/cleansed')` to see if it can list the directory and if it shows the file there first

Comment: it does show that the file is in  dbutils.fs.ls. How would i save it into my gen 2 account?

Comment: Could you please provide the error which you have got?

Comment: I don't particularly have an error, I'M trying to save a parquet file onto my azure storage account, However it's saved onto the file system in databricks but not in my storage account. I've ran df.write.parquet("/mnt/youtubedataset/youtube/cleansed"), but when I go into my storage account it's empty, even when I refresh the page.

Comment: I tried adding this code 
newdf.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/mnt/container-name/directory-name/")

Comment: when I go and check the datalake the files are empty. there is no error

Comment: Have you checked if /mnt/youtubedataset/youtube/cleansed is linked to the same ADLS gen 2 which you are referring to?  You can do this using the display(dbutils.fs.mounts()) command. If you are seeing the file using the dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/youtubedataset/youtube/cleansed') command, that means the file has been written but you need to validate which physical location that points to.

Comment: @AnupamChand,  
The file has been written, so how would i validate the physical location it points to? This is my first time using Databricks.

Comment: Use the display(dbutils.fs.mounts()) command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215897/how-to-list-all-the-mount-points-in-azure-databricks

Comment: Was it being written into a different physical location ?

Comment: @Anupam Chad, it was. I found out how to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue as follows:

I have mounted my ADLS container using below code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access-Key>"  
  }
)
```

[image]

I tried to write dataframe into parquet file format into ADLS account using below code:

```
data = [("Alice", 28), ("Bob", 22), ("Charlie", 35)]
columns = ["Name", "Age"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/mnt/youtubedataset\youtube\cleansed")
```

[image]

It wrote successfully as mentioned in above image but when I saw in storage account there is no files in it as mentioned below:

[image]

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215897/how-to-list-all-the-mount-points-in-azure-databricks) the folders in `dbfs:/mnt/` that are not actually mounted volumes but just simple folders. That's why I have checked the location of my mount point using `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())`  it located the mount location as storage account as mentioned below:

[image]

I have added forward slash to the storage path instead of back slash as mentioned below:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/mnt/youtubedataset/youtube/cleansed")
```

[image]

The file wrote successfully into ADLS storage account:

[image]

Once check your mount point is located to storage account.

Comment: Thank you @Bhavani,for taking the time to show me.  The solution worked.