# Reading the latest file from a folder in data lake in Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

I have the following code:

```py
directory_path = "dbfs:/mnt/x_file_directory"
files = dbutils.fs.ls(directory_path)
latest_file = max(files, key=lambda f:f.modificationTime)
latest_file_path = latest_file.path
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .csv(latest_file_path).toPandas()
```

I receive the error message: `AnalysisException: [PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/x_file_directory/file_name`.

The file path looks correct so where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the approach below for reading the latest file from an ADLS folder:

I mounted my ADLS container using the following code:

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access-Key>"  
  }
)
```

[image]

I read the latest file from the data lake folder using the code below:

```py
directory_path = "dbfs:/mnt/files/input"
files = dbutils.fs.ls(directory_path)
latest_file = max(files, key=lambda f:f.modificationTime)
latest_file_path = latest_file.path
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true") \
      .csv(latest_file_path).toPandas()
print(df)
```

[image]

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215897/how-to-list-all-the-mount-points-in-azure-databricks), the folders in `dbfs:/mnt/` are not actually mounted volumes but just simple folders. That's why I checked the location of my mount point using `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())` and found it located at the storage account as mentioned below:

[image]

Please check if your mount point is located in the storage account.